# "portable" way to determine GPU core occupancy with Vulkan

Tags: gpu, shader, vulkan, compute-shader

For writing GPU computation kernels (aka "compute shaders" in GL/Vulkan), it is useful to query various shader parameters such as register usage and shared memory usage that determine how much individual threads may get scheduled to a single streaming multiprocessor (SM with nVidia, CU with AMD, etc.).

For AMD GPUs, we have an [appropriate extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_AMD_shader_info.html) that contains `vkGetShaderInfoAMD`, using which one can reach some information about occupied VGPR/SGPRs and shared memory (aka LDS) and thus calculate a good estimate of the core occupancy.

Is there any such possibility/extension for nVidia and Intel (and possibly other) GPUs, or a workaround to measure the properties of a GLSL shader on a particular hardware in some other way? At least for nVidia cards, the functionality [is implemented in CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL.html#group__CUDART__HIGHLEVEL_1gee5334618ed4bb0871e4559a77643fc1), but that doesn't help much with debugging GLSL shaders stuff.